# Authorization Header in angular 4

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have a server(Spring Boot) that sends me Authorization with a JWT when successful authentication occurs.  All of that works fine.  I'm able to see that the Authorization header is being returned in the Chromes Network tab.  But for some reason When I try to print the headers in angular using the console.log the Authorization header is not showing up.  Also the headers.get('Authorization') is not working as well.

```
login(user) {
this.http
  .post(`${this.url}/login`, user)
  .subscribe((h:Response) => {
    console.log(h.headers.toJSON());  // Doesn't print Authorization header
    console.log(h.headers.get('Authorization')); // prints null
    //this.setToken(h.headers.get('Authorization'));
  });
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your service might not be returning the `Authorization` header

Comment: It is returning the Authorization header.  I'm able to spot it in the Chrome's network tab and I double checked it using postman.

Comment: `res.data.token` or `res.body.token` is normally where you'd get a jwt back with a post

Comment: Put a break point and see if your getting. Are you available in TeamViewer?

Answer (score 0):

So, after doing a bit more research I ran into this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/43734000/7770219  which answers the questions above.  I didn't have my CorsFilters configured properly.  Which is why, the frontend(angular 2+) cann't get access to the Authorization token which holds my JWT.  Even though you are able to see the token in the postman and Chromes Network tab that doesn't mean that your front end is able to successfully access it.  To do that Use the link provided above to give it access.